# What's mean that syntax in JS?

Tags: javascript

I found in web script, allowed unwind div.

```
function toggle(sDivId) {
    var oDiv = document.getElementById(sDivId);
    oDiv.style.display = (oDiv.style.display == "none") ? "block" : "none";
}
```

Whats mean that line: `(oDiv.style.display == "none") ? "block" : "none";`

Comment: [Conditional (ternary) operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

it's a [ternary operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator), or "inline if" as some call it

```
oDiv.style.display = (oDiv.style.display == "none") ? "block" : "none";
```

is the same as:

```
if(oDiv.style.display == "none") {
    oDiv.style.display = "block";
} else {
    oDiv.style.display = "none";
}
```

Comment: so simple, thanks :)

Answer (score -1):

This is `ternary` operator. More information [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator)

> condition ? expr1 : expr2
>
> If condition is true, the operator returns the value of expr1;
>   otherwise, it returns the value of expr2.

Basically, a short hand of `If else` statement.

```
if(oDiv.style.display == "none")) {
 oDiv.style.display = "block" } 
else {
oDiv.style.display = "none";}
```

Answer (score -1):

This is a ternary operator, it is basically saying the following...

> Is display = "none"? If so, set "block", if not set "none"

Simply put...

> Condition?true:false;

```
function toggle(sDivId) {
            var oDiv = document.getElementById(sDivId);
            oDiv.style.display = (oDiv.style.display == "none") ? "block" : "none";
            // Is this element display set to none? ? yes  ? no
           }
```